# How to get the entire html source from determined url?

Tags: java, web-scraping

I'm having a problem to catch the URL from the video from this link:

http://bleachproject.com/Bleach.php?epi=001&url=/epis/LQ/bP001_LQ.mp4

I need to get the video link to download the video. It appears if I try to get it by F12, inspect element... But if I try to get the HTML source, it doesn't appears.
I tried to use Jsoup, HTMLUnit but still not working...
Someone know another way to get the entire html source from this webpage?

Answer (score 0):

When using curl on this address I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 13:41:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://www.bleachproject.net/Bleach.php?epi=001&url=/epis/LQ/bP001_LQ.mp4
Content-Length: 184
Age: 482
Via: 1.1 isrwbs7
```

Calling curl for the new address yields another redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 13:39:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://www.aliancaproject.com.br
Content-Length: 184
Age: 482
Via: 1.1 isrwbs7
```

My guess is that the original page was viewed under session, and this is why I get the redirects. I suggest you follow the links using tool like the chrome developer tool or proxy server like Fidler and view the actual requests and responses. Once you can model the web navigation properly you would be able to use an headless browser such as HTMLUnit to mimic this navigation.

Another option is to use the [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) plugin and convert its recording to Java code.